# curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:

Tags: windows, curl, solr

I am running an Apache Solr tutorial from here:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/solr-tutorial.html

Solr is running and I can run queries in a web browser.

The tutorial mentions `cURL` which I am unfamiliar with.

I have unzipped `CURL` to `C:\Curl` and included Curl in the `PATH environment variable`: `C:\Curl\curl-7.63.0-win64-mingw\bin`

I am getting an error when running the Command below in a Windows command prompt.  I have googled to try and find a resolution to no avail:

Code below:

```
C:\Curl\curl-7.63.0-win64-mingw\bin>curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"name", "type":"text_general", "multiValued":false, "stored":true}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema
```

generates the following error:

```
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:
{name:name,
 ^
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 12:
stored:true}}'
           ^
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"no stream",
    "code":400}}
```

I tried adding a `-g` to turn off globbing.

```
curl -g -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"name", "type":"text_general", "multiValued":false, "stored":true}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema
```

This generated an almost identical error:

```
C:\Curl\curl-7.63.0-win64-mingw\bin>curl -g -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"name", "type":"text_general", "multiValued":false, "stored":true}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"no stream",
    "code":400}}
```

I then tried removing the single quotes and escaping the double quotes, but then got the below error:

```
curl -g -X POST -H Content-type:application/json --data-binary {\"add-field\": {\"name\":\"name\", \"type\":\"text_general\", \"multiValued\":false, \"stored\":true}} http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema
```

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":4},
  "error":{
    "msg":"Premature EOF: char=(EOF),position=11 AFTER=''",
    "trace":"org.noggit.JSONParser$ParseException: Premature EOF: char=(EOF),position=11 AFTER=''\r\n\tat org.noggit.JSONParser.err(JSONParser.java:419)\r\n\tat org.noggit.JSONParser.next(JSONParser.j
ava:973)\r\n\tat org.noggit.JSONParser.nextEvent(JSONParser.java:1061)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.common.util.CommandOperation.parse(CommandOperation.java:285)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.common.util.Command
Operation.readCommands(CommandOperation.java:350)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.common.util.CommandOperation.readCommands(CommandOperation.java:326)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag.getCommandOperations(A
piBag.java:289)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.getCommands(HttpSolrCall.java:1073)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers$1.getCommands(SolrRequestParsers.java:245)\r\n\tat o
rg.apache.solr.schema.SchemaManager.performOperations(SchemaManager.java:77)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.SchemaHandler.handleRequestBody(SchemaHandler.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.Requ
estHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2541)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)\
r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDi
spatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHa
ndle(ServletHandler.java:533)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\
r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.je
tty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.
ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(Serv
letHandler.java:473)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\
r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jett
y.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.je
tty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.Hand
lerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)\r\n\tat org.eclipse
.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillIn
terest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill
.java:333)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java
:168)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.
java:366)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)\r\n\tat java.
lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n",
    "code":500}}

I know there are a lot of similar Q&A's on SO regarding this issue but they are not quite the same and none of the solutions I have tried resolve my issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I replaced the single quotes with double quote and escaped the double quotes inside the curly braces with a backslash and it has worked.

I went from this:

```
curl --X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field": {"name":"name", "type":"text_general", "multiValued":false, "stored":true}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema
```

to this:

```
curl --X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data-binary "{\"add-field\": {\"name\":\"name\", \"type\":\"text_general\", \"multiValued\":false, \"stored\":true}}" http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema
```

Thank you everybody for your collective answers.  I am sure there are some possible positives to adding the `JSON` to a separate file but i wanted to avoid the creation of additional files.

Answer (score 4):

The Windows command prompt doesn't support single quotes. It's a problem because cURL statements use single quotes to specify JSON data.

To fix the problem, save the JSON in a separate file (e.g. `add-field.txt`) and import it into the cURL statement, so later you could run it like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary @add-field.txt http://localhost:8983/solr/films/schema
```

Comment: This was the best solution for me. I went down a rabbit hole of escaping quotes, brackets, braces etc. until the command was illegible. Putting it in a separate file restores clarity, and has the added benefit that you can break up over multiple lines, and indent. I used "--data".

Answer (score 3):

I would go another route. If you install Microsoft's wonderfool tool [WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL). You will be able to run all those commands as is, as you will be running inside a linux system. It will be a big time saver eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Gitbash solved it for me.
WSL was crashing for a reason I ignore at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this worked for me:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data "$DATA" http://localhost/...
```

Where $DATA is a shell varible containing JSON data and is enclosed in doub;e-quotes.  This was in a Linux environment where I was having the same issue.